# Como posso testar método com retorno void utilizando JUnit?

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, junit

É possível realizar teste automatizado, em `Java`, de um método que possui retorno `void` utilizando `JUnit`? Se sim, como é possível?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você testa os side-effects causado pelo método. Por exemplo se seu método void altera algum atributo da classe o teste deve checar se antes da chamada o valor do atributo era X e após a chamada mudou para Y, exemplo:

```
class TarefaDeCasa {
    public String feita = "Não";

    public void perguntarNoStackoverflow() {
        this.feita = "Sim";
    }
}

public class TestJunit {
   @Test
   public void testPerguntarNoStackoverflow() {
        TarefaDeCasa t = new TarefaDeCasa();
        assertEquals("Não", t.feita);

        t.perguntarNoStackoverflow();
        assertEquals("Sim", t.feita);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Além da resposta do Bruno, vale adicionar uma outra forma de testar métodos que retornam `void`.

Muitas vezes, estes métodos pertencem a classes com dependências. Situação clássica quando estamos trabalhando com uma camada de serviços. Exemplo:

```
class AlgumService {

    private final DependenciaService dependenciaService;

    public void alterar (Usuario usuario, String nome) {
        usuario.alterarNome(nome);
        dependenciaService.enviar(usuario);
    }
}
```

No método acima, você pode conferir se o usuário foi alterado:

```
 AlgumService algumService = new AlgumService(mock(DependenciaService.class));
 Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
 algumService.alterar(usuario , "Joaquim");
 assert("Joaquim", usuario.getNome());
```

**Porém**, como verificar que o `DependenciaService` foi chamado? Com ajuda de um framework de mock, podemos fazer o `verify` disto:

```
DependenciaService dependenciaService = mock(DependenciaService.class)
AlgumService algumService = new AlgumService(dependenciaService );
Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
algumService.alterar(usuario , "Joaquim");

assert("Joaquim", usuario.getNome());
verify(dependenciaService ).enviar(any(Usuario.class));
```

E garantir não só que o `usuario` foi alterado, mas que nosso serviço foi chamado.

Comment: Essa resposta foi a que de fato me ajudou!